# syntax to unpack tuple on parameter pack and variadic template

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++20

I have an example parameter pack function:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all_values_equal(T first, Args... args) {
    return ((first == args) && ...);
}

static_assert(all_values_equal(1, 1, 1.0));
```

I often use `std::tuple` as I like to be able to work with templates. Extracting types, Slicing types and other arrangements.

how can I call this function with an `std::tuple`?

```
template<typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all_values_equal(std::tuple<Args...> tuple) {
    return /* ??? */ ;
}

static_assert(all_values_equal(std::make_tuple(1, 1, 1.0)));
```

---

I would also like know the case for variadic template functions with no arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all_types_equal() {
    return (std::is_same_v<T, Args> && ...);
}

template <template<typename ... Args> class Tuple>
constexpr bool all_types_equal() {
    return /* ??? */ ;
}

static_assert(all_types_equal<int, int>());
static_assert(all_types_equal<std::tuple<int, int>>());
```

ultimately I want to be able to call all 4 variations like this:

```
static_assert(all_values_equal(1, 1, 1.0));
static_assert(all_values_equal(std::make_tuple(1, 1, 1.0)));
static_assert(all_types_equal<int, int>());
static_assert(all_types_equal<std::tuple<int, int>>());
```

and the `std::tuple` functions should not re-implement the logic of the variadic template functions.
how can I achieve this in a clean and modern way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::apply` let's you call a function with the tuple elements as parameters. You can use that with a lambda.

```
template<typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all_values_equal(std::tuple<Args...> tuple) {
    auto cmp = [](auto&& first, auto&&... args) {
        return ((first == args) && ...);
    };

    return std::apply(cmp, tuple);
}
```

To make the `all_types_equal` check we can use partial specialization. Something like this.

```
template <typename First, typename ... Rest>
constexpr bool all_types_equal_impl = (std::is_same_v<First, Rest> && ...);;

template <typename First, typename ... Rest>
constexpr bool all_types_equal_impl<std::tuple<First, Rest...>> = (std::is_same_v<First, Rest> && ...);

template <typename... Args>
constexpr bool all_types_equal() {
    return all_types_equal_impl<Args...>;
}
```

We can refer to the template variable directly, so wrapping it in a function is not really required if we don't want to.

Comment: I considered `std::apply` and was confused when it failed to call the variadic function, looks like you can't pass templated functions (which makes sense). using a lambda as a middle step is an interesting solution, thanks

Comment: A) `return (args == ...);` this does not do what you think it does; it compares the first two tuple elements for equality, but thereafter compares the next element with the _result of_ the first comparison, which is a boolean, and which (by coincidence of the examples, using numeric 1 entries) compares as "truthy" to 1 (try this for a tuple with all 2 entries for example), and B) as the cmp lambda does not capture anything, using a default reference capture is superfluous (and arguably confusing).

Comment: the lambda re implements the logic which is undesirable. so it should be `auto cmd = [](auto&&... args) { return all_values_equal(args...); };` I would also like to know if there is a solution to the template-only function (other than the one I wrote).

Comment: @StackDanny Added an example for the type checks.

Comment: this is getting close to what I want, but not quite. I edited the bottom of my question to clarify further.

Comment: @StackDanny That's an easy modification, just make the base template check on types directly and leave the tuple specialization as is. Updated the answer.

Comment: @StackDanny You can also wrap the types in `std::decay_t` if you want to relax the requirements for what is considered equal types.

Answer (score 0):

using an [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) allows to access each data field and each type of a `std::tuple`.
since C++20 lambda's can be templated, this allows an inline unpacking.

```
template<typename ... Args>
constexpr bool all_values_equal(std::tuple<Args...> tuple) {

    constexpr auto unpack_tuple = []<typename Tuple, size_t... Ints>(Tuple tuple, std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        return all_values_equal(std::get<Ints>(tuple)...);
    };
    return unpack_tuple(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(tuple)>>());
}

template <template<typename ... Args> class Tuple>
constexpr bool all_types_equal() {

    constexpr auto unpack_tuple = []<typename Tuple, size_t... Ints>(std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
        return all_types_equal<std::tuple_element_t<Ints, Tuple>...>();
    };
    return unpack_tuple.template operator()<Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>());
}


static_assert(all_values_equal(1, 1, 1.0));
static_assert(all_values_equal(std::make_tuple(1, 1, 1.0)));
static_assert(all_types_equal<int, int>());
static_assert(all_types_equal<std::tuple<int, int>>());
```

- [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and [`std::tuple_size_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size) are convenient utilities from the standard.
- `std::get<Int>(tuple)...` unpacks the values, `std::tuple_element_t<Ints, Tuple>...` unpacks the types.
- `.template operator()<Tuple>(...)` allows to specify a template of a templated lambda